# I can't align center a content by using CSS

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I can't align center the two block between div class="wrapper-home"

The site is: [www.mattialab.it/wp/](http://www.mattialab.it/wp/)
I just already try by using in `body:` 
`text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto;` without any result.
Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong or what is missing?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a width so it knows where to center. Make it 900px and it centers it.

Comment: where should I add the width?

Comment: To your wrapper-header div

Comment: show me what you did, works for me

Comment: i add in wrapper-home (sorry.. isn't wrapper-header) width: 100%

Comment: Don't use a % you need to put in pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a width to your container div so the margin's know where to start and stop the centering.

CSS

```
.wrapper-header{
margin: 0 auto;
width:900px;
}
```